# A package error

Tags: android, eclipse, package

When I run a simple hello world program, this error happens...

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching 1.HelloWorld".
com.android.ddmlib.IDevice.installRemotePackage(Ljava/lange/String;Z[Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I updated the Android Development Tools for Eclipse but not the other packages like DDMS, Traceview, etc. Go to Check for Updates and grab all the Android updates listed there.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the application, restarting eclipse, cleaning your project (<kbd>Window</kbd> --> <kbd>Clean...</kbd>), etc.